# Is it possible to hide %comments and \usepackage code without creating a section?

Tags: packages, overleaf

I´m using a tex template that I have never used before and there are some packages that I don´t really know how to use, so I figured I´d leave the %comments so I can know what they can be used for... but the comments are pretty detailed and long, so I was wondering if it is possible to just hide that first part so I dont have to scroll down a lot to start writing. Thank you!

Comment: Overleaf remembers where you were in the document when you open it again, so the extra scrolling would only be needed when you create the document for the first time. But if you want to hide the commented lines then you can always make a second file where you put these lines in, and copy a line back to your main document (and uncomment it) when you want to use one of those packages.

Comment: you can stick the entire preamble in a file say `mypreamble.sty` and your main document just have `\usepackage{mypreamble}` then the code and comments are only seen if you explicitly open up that package file.